# Under what circumstances could an app ever receive TCP packets out of sequence?

Tags: tcp, mqtt

I'm trying to get my head around the wording of a protocol which infers apps were once able to receive TCP packet data out of sequence. That's **applications** receiving data out of sequence not the IP packets showing up at the host out of sequence.

This is curious. I'm unaware of any implementation of TCP that could ever allow this to happen. I think that would always have violated a core principle of TCP.

Can anyone explain [this passage in the MQTT 3.1.1 standard](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc398718103):

> When a Client reconnects with CleanSession set to 0, both the Client and Server MUST re-send any unacknowledged PUBLISH Packets (where QoS > 0) and PUBREL Packets using their original Packet Identifiers [MQTT-4.4.0-1]. This is the only circumstance where a Client or Server is REQUIRED to redeliver messages.
>
> Non normative comment
> **Historically retransmission of Control Packets was required to overcome data loss on some older TCP networks.** This might remain a concern where MQTT 3.1.1 implementations are to be deployed in such environments.

MQTT is connection orientated so resending at any other time would explicitly mean sending the same "control packet" down the same TCP connection twice. **If the data didn't arrive the first time, surely the receiving host would block the application from receiving any further data. Resending it would be futile**.

Indeed, this is in complete contrast to the later [MQTT 5.0 standard](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_Toc3901238):

> When a Client reconnects with Clean Start set to 0 and a session is present, both the Client and Server MUST resend any unacknowledged PUBLISH packets (where QoS > 0) and PUBREL packets using their original Packet Identifiers. This is the only circumstance where a Client or Server is REQUIRED to resend messages. **Clients and Servers MUST NOT resend messages at any other time** [MQTT-4.4.0-1].

Were the authors originally mistaken?  Was re-transmitting data (by the application) through the same TCP connection ever required to handle data loss?  Or was this passage in the standard simply misleading and not what the authors intended?

*Note that this is not just my inference of this wording.  I have seen mainstream implementations of this protocol periodically re-transmitting the same packets down the same TCP connection.*

Comment: `When a Client reconnects with CleanSession set to 0` -- I assume that this invalidates the original TCP/IP connection.

Comment: I think the non-normative comment explains this: things didn’t work so well in the past, and the fact you’re unaware of this doesn’t mean anything more than that you are unaware of this. The MQTT authors weren’t imagining this or making it up. Things around networking were different/worse/slower/less reliable in the past and have improved significantly. MQTT will re-transmit a MQTT packet if it doesn’t get acknowledgement of delivery, but that’s an MQTT protocol function, not related to the underlying (in this case) TCP/IP protocol. Don’t confuse MQTT re-sending with unrelated TCP resending

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think you've got the right idea.  Connecting with the same "client id" as a another connection disconnects that old connection (if it was still live).  `CleanSession` indicates whether the session from the previous connection should be transferred to this one or deleted and a new session started for this connection.

Comment: It certainly wasn’t nonsense when the authors wrote that, whatever you think. When a network connection gets bad nasty unlikely unpredictable things happen - these days we’re used to good fast low-latency network connections so maybe for you this is unimaginable, but years ago things weren’t so good. The authors weren’t imagining things: TCP stacks on very flaky networks did occasionally deliver garbage out of sequence, and the MQTT authors experienced that. TBH I don’t understand why you’re so resistant to the thought that things were different when the MQTT authors wrote that paragraph.

Comment: I don’t mind what colour your hair is. The fact remains the MQTT authors wrote those words for a reason, however much you dislike/disbelieve it or deride it as nonsese.

Comment: @barny Yes but all you have done in comments is re-iterate what they have said, you've just lectured on flaky networks - an issue which is fundamentally different from packet ordering by host machines.  What I'm looking for is a lot more specific than that.  Any evidence of what systems they were referring to or specific known behaviour (preferably with citations of personal experience) would be great here.  Just saying "networking was unreliable" is pretty unhelpful here.

Comment: Keep in mind that a modern TCP/IP stack will NOT deliver packets up to an app out of sequence.  It will just retain the OOS packet in the chance that the proper packet does arrive and it can then use that retained packet.  If your MQTT solution is resending PUBLISH packets set to QOS = 2, there could be other reasons why that is happening at the Protocol level, NOT the TCP level.

Comment: Your quotations do not imply what you claim. They speak of data loss, not delivery out of sequence. The idea that any TCP stack of any vintage whatsover would deliver data out of order is risible.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne the point is that when the application resends over the same tcp, it could only be done in the belief that the re-sent version would arrive before the first version (lost). Would that not constitute out of sequence?

Comment: @PhilipCouling 'Arrive before the first version (lost)' is a contradiction in terms.

Comment: @Marquisoflone try to be a little more tolerant of others’ use of English. If you have a better expression then feel free to offer an [edit]. I have used the expression “out of sequence” to describe delivering packets in the order 1,2,3,5,6,7 where there is still a chance that 4 could arrive late. 4 is expected to arrive late as TCP dictates that the sender should resend (or so I thought)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this is about packet loss, not out of order delivery.

A very early (may be even the first) deployment of MQTT was on a network that used a form of satellite back haul where the satellite modem would respond with ack packets before the actual packet was transmitted to the satellite so it was possible for the client to believe that the packet had been received by the broker when it had in fact been lost (either on the way up to satellite or the way back down) on route.

Comment: Wow, do you have a reference to that behaviour. I’m trying to imagine what reason they had for promiscuously sending ACK packets it seems a very strange thing to do indeed.

Comment: Many hours spent talking with Andy Stanford-Clark (co-creator of MQTT), The reasoning iirc was because the modem had a large MTU and would buffer data until it was full so as not to send half empty packets to the sats (which had a huge cost)

Comment: @PhilipCouling This isn't making any sense. There is nothing about out of order delivery in your quotations, either expressed or implied. If you think otherwise it is up to you to show why.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne on the contrary, it's in **bold** between the two quotes from different standards... if packets are delivered before their predecessor then they are delivered out of sequence.  As hardillb infers the predecessor may never actually arrive at all, in which case we're just arguing semantics as to wether or not this classes as out of sequence.

Comment: @hardillb thanks, it’s this type of personal connections that make stackoverflow great!  This answer gives a good flavour of what the MQTT standard was trying to accommodate.